# How to group dates in a pivot tables with extra (non-date) columns

Tags: excel, vba, grouping, pivot-table

I have some data with "Completion Dates". These dates range from 1/1/19 to middle of 2020. But some of the dates are not set yet and the data says "Missing". I am trying to automate a pivot table using a macro. I need the dates to be a column based in quarters. It also needs a column for 2020 and a column for MISSING. So it will read:

|Missing|--|Q1 2019|--|Q2 2019|--|Q3 2019|--|Q4 2019|--|2020|

The missing can be wither at the front or back (but prefer the front).

I cannot hard code the cell locations since the dates can change, be added, or deleted at anytime. I know how to group by date, but the MISSING is breaking everything I've tried.

This needs to be completely done in VBA. I don't want any manual input.

Comment: Can you make a helper column that will group the dates accordingly?

Comment: @dwirony I really wanted to go around that but seemed to be the only thing that worked. Appreciate the help.